# Deserializing unreliable JSON efficiently

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON from the server which sometimes omits certain key/values, which prevented me from using it:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Obj>(respString);
```

I read up the JSON.net documentation and went ahead with his Linq to JSON deserialization which looks like this:

```
string respString = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(respString);

...

CustomObject.child.primary_key = int.Parse(obj[i]["primary_key"].ToString());
CustomObject.foreign_key = obj[i]["foreign_key"].ToString();
CustomObject.properties = int.Parse(ojb[i]["properties"].ToString());

try //this is being done a few times throughout the loop
{
    CustomObject.unreliableProperty = obj[i]["xxx"].ToString();
}
Catch { }
```

Everything works fine but I occasionally get `outofmemoryexceptions` (the JSON from the server is quite big). I've tried implementing a custom `JsonConverter` from JSON.net but with the nested hierarchy (3-level depth), the `JsonConverter` gets too complicated and hard to understand, not to mention maintain.

When I run the memory profiler, I saw peaks above 150mb, which would cause the application to have OOM exceptions. Under the heap section, I saw 30-40% of the memory allocations are done by `mscorlib` due to string allocation. Another problem was during the loop, there was a continuous streak of GC going on. I am utterly disgusted by the way it's being written now, but I have reached my wit's end, can anyone help?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with JSON.Net and "sometimes missing" (unreliable?) properties. If the key/value pairs are missing in the JSON, the properties/fields in the POCOs simply won't be assigned during Deserialize - not really much else to do there anyway.

Comment: Mark the required properties with `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`.  See [Json.NET MissingMemberHandling setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147404/json-net-missingmemberhandling-setting/18147643#18147643) and http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm