# Json.NET MissingMemberHandling setting

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I would like `Json.NET` to throw a `JsonSerializationException` when the `Json` string is missing a property that the C# class requires.

There is the [`MissingMemberHandling Enumeration`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm) which

> Throw a JsonSerializationException when a missing member is
>   encountered during deserialization.

but I think this is the reverse of what I want. I think this means a missing member on the c# class. I want a missing Json member.

My code is

```
public MyObj Deserialise(string json)
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    jsonSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiMessage>(json, jsonSettings);
}
```

For example

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{ ""P1"": ""foo"" }";
```

P2 is missing from the json. I want to know when this is the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to set the P2 property to mandatory with the `JsonPropertyAttribute`

```
public class ApiMessage
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

With your example, you will get an `JsonSerializationException`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Use `JsonObject` on the class to mark all properties required:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class MyObj
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
    public string P2 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
}
```

Use `JsonProperty` to mark individual properties required:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }  // Required.Default

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string P2 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
}
```

Use both in combination to do things like mark all but one property required:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class MyObj
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
    public string P2 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
    public string P3 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
    public string P4 { get; set; }  // Required.Always
    public string P5 { get; set; }  // Required.Always

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
    public string P6 { get; set; }  // Required.Default
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the class, but rather make the change at the settings level? and how would I do that using `DataContract` and `DataMember` instead?

Comment: @orirab This is what I was wondering too. I only found an answer talking about overriding the default ContractResolver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754463/json-net-ignore-property-during-deserialization