# Is it possible to determine which properties were deserialised in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, .net-4.8

Suppose I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Jim",
  "age": 20
}
```

And I deserialise it into the following C# object:

```
public class Person
{
  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("age")]
  public int? Age    { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("height")]
  public int? Height { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can determine which properties were included in the the original JSON, and which were omitted?

In this example all my properties are nullable, the JSON didn't include the `height` property, so my C# object will have end up with a `null` `Height`.

However it's also possible that a user could simply provide `null` as the height, e.g.

```
{
  "name": "Jim",
  "age": 20,
  "height": null
}
```

So my question is:  Is it possible for me to determine if the value was provided but `null`, or not provided and therefore defaulting to `null`.  Is there some meta data available somewhere/somehow that gives me this information?

This is used in an ApiController, so the deserialization is done by a Formatter automatically, but here is my current formatter setup:

```
private static void AddFormatter(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var formatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

    formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting       = Formatting.Indented,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None
    };
}
```

Comment: What's the difference, in business logic terms, between not supplying height and height being supplied as null?

Comment: This is an example intermediate object I use to update some other data.  Preferably I'd like to only set fields on the final object that were provided in the initial JSON.

Comment: [How to configure JSON.net deserializer to track missing properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30300740/3744182) looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Comment: @dbc Agreed, thanks for the find!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DefaultValueHandling` attribute to define the strategy for handling nullable values like `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]`, you can read more options [here.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm)

try adding the default value that user can't provide and then you'd know if the value was user provided or not.

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int? Age    { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(-1)] 
    [JsonProperty("height", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public int? Height { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Not sure how this helps me achieve my goal...?

Comment: try adding default value, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of response, barring the helpful but not brilliant suggestion by [svyatis.lviv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512914/svyatis-lviv) I decided to implement it in a simple non serialisation related way.

First I made this inteface:

```
public interface IPropertyChangeLog
{
    IEnumerable<string> PropertiesChanged { get; }
    void Reset();
}
```

Then I made this helper class:

```
public class PropertyChangeLog<TSource> : IPropertyChangeLog
    where TSource : IPropertyChangeLog
{
    private readonly List<string> _changes = new List<string>();

    public void UpdateProperty<TValue>(TValue newValue, ref TValue oldValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        oldValue = newValue;
        _changes.Add(propertyName);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> PropertiesChanged => _changes;
    public void Reset() => _changes.Clear();
}
```

And finally, I updated the `Person` class as follows:

```
public class Person : IPropertyChangeLog
{
    private PropertyChangeLog<Person> _log = new PropertyChangeLog<Person>();
    private string _name;
    private int? _age;
    private int? _height;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _log.UpdateProperty(value, ref _name);
    }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int? Age
    {
        get => _age;
        set => _log.UpdateProperty(value, ref _age);
    }

    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public int? Height
    {
        get => _height;
        set => _log.UpdateProperty(value, ref _height);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> IPropertyChangeLog.PropertiesChanged => _log.PropertiesChanged;
    void IPropertyChangeLog.Reset() => _log.Reset();
}
```

It's a little more verbose than I'd like, but it's still pretty simple and readable.

In order to use it:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>("{ \"name\": \"test\" }");
var log = (IPropertyChangeLog)person;

// log.PropertiesChanged should now contain 'Name'

foreach (var property in log.PropertiesChanged)
{
    // we know that the property named in 'property' changed
}

log.Reset();

JsonConvert.PopulateObject("{ \"age\": null }", person);

// now log.PropertiesChanged should only contain 'Age'

foreach (var property in log.PropertiesChanged)
{
    // we know that the property named in 'property' changed
}
```