# How to check for missing field in JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have this JSON :

```
{
    "Foo": "A value",
    "Bar": 42
}
```

To deserialize it, I have this class :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm deserializing it using :

```
string json1 = "{\"Foo\":\"A value\",\"Bar\":42}";
var MyObj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json1);
Debug.WriteLine("Foo1 : " + MyObj1.Foo); //Foo1 : A value
Debug.WriteLine("Bar1 : " + MyObj1.Bar); //Bar1 : 42
```

I need a specific treatment when a field is missing from JSON.

In example :

```
{
    "Foo": "Another value"
}
```

When using the same code than above, `Bar` is set to 0. It could have been set to 0 in the original JSON, so I can't tell with this value if it was existing or not.

```
string json2 = "{\"Foo\":\"Another value\"}";
var MyObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json2);
Debug.WriteLine("Foo2 : " + MyObj2.Foo); //Foo2 : Another value
Debug.WriteLine("Bar2 : " + MyObj2.Bar); //Bar2 : 0
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: As an aside, if you want the app to fail when members are missing, you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147404/json-net-missingmemberhandling-setting

Comment: @DavidG thank you. I saw this topic, but the missing member, in my case, is a normal behaviour and shouldn't throw an exception at deserialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option would be to make it an `int?` property, then check whether the value is null afterwards:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int? Bar { get; set; }
}

...

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
if (deserialized.Bar == null)
{
    // Whatever you want to do if it wasn't set
}
```

Of course, the JSON could *explicitly* set the value to null, but I expect you'd probably be happy handling that as if it was missing.

Comment: -facepalm- Obviously, `int?` Thank you.